# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Black Screen after wake and login

Tags: mate, wakeup

Dual Boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 16.04
Mate Desktop Enviroment
i7 6700k
EVO GFX 960
32GB RAM

I having problems with my system waking from sleep/screen saver/ monitors turn off. The problem is: if I leave my computer and the monitors go off, when I wake the computer I get a login screen with a black background, I login and then its just a black background with a mouse cursor. I've been able to do this once (after a shorter period of being away..so it probably just turned the screensaver on and didn't go to sleep) and was able to login and go back to normal use. Currently I have turned all screen savers and what not off so that my computer doesn't go to sleep, but I would like to fix this problem so that my monitors will turn off and things will go to sleep like they are suppose to.

Are there any suggestions? I have tried to enter the terminal when I do this but it doesn't work... nothing responds at all it seems except the mouse cursor.